# How should I handle Google Play requesting data safety forms for long-unpublished / EOL apps?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-console, developer-console

Some background: over 10 years ago, I published a few apps to the Play Store (or, Android Store as IIRC it was called at the time). They were used to help navigate the London Underground. These were live for about a year or two until their functionality was superceded by modern alternatives (basically, when Google added its transit layer to Maps). I unpublished them at that time (circa 2012) and basically forgot about them completely.

Fast forward 10 years, Google are now asking me to fill out a bunch of data safety and privacy forms. I have done so in the hope that they stop nagging me, however one of the sections I have to fill out relates to "Sensitive permissions / APIs" - specifically, fine location access. At the time, one of the apps requested the user's location (possibly in the background; I don't recall) and used it to locally render a dot on a Map activity to show where they were, and also to work out where their nearest station was. This data was never sent off-device. This was obviously targeting a very old version of Android (latest it ran on was probably ICS or Jelly Bean).

It appears that I can just state in the form that the app targets a version older than Pie and doesn't meet the location requirements, but would that then trigger a requirement that I need to provide a new APK with a fix? I'm not even sure if I still have the original source code.

Does any of this even matter if I never intend to make the apps available again (or, based on this experience, ever publish anything else to the Play Store)?

Ideally, I'd like to delete both apps entirely, but from what I gather Google have intentionally made this impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can ignore these, as long as they don't state that it will suspend your account. Choose the option that you need to declare those data collection, and simply declare everything.